# Defining custom collection class based on list. How to access elements that are stored in the instance?

Tags: c#, class, generics, generic-list

Creating custom data collection class that inherits methods from List. This new type holds items in a queue, has private dictionary that holds all the items and corresponding IDs that when new item is add checks if there already is item with same ID in the queue and replaces it. Wondering is there way to access that element (which has same ID) and overwrite it.

I already implemented a way that when there are two items with same ID, code finds index of the item in queue, deletes it, inserts new item and updates the dictionary. It works perfectly, but I am wondering if there is a way make this action more efficient and thought that overwriting is easier than deleting and inserting.

```
public void Enqueue(T item, string uniqueID)
    {
        if (entries.ContainsKey(uniqueID))
        {
            int index = base.IndexOf(entries[uniqueID]);
            base.Remove(entries[uniqueID]);
            base.Insert(index, item);
            entries[uniqueID] = item;
        }
        else
        {
            base.Add(item);
            entries.Add(uniqueID, item);
        }
    }
```

`entries` is the dictionary that holds string and T

This entire class definition

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System;
using System.Linq;
/// <summary>
/// Queue based on class that has only one entry with unique ID
/// </summary>
/// /// /// <remarks>
/// When adding value with same ID old value is overwriten but place in the queue is maintained
/// </remarks>
/// <typeparam name="T"></typeparam>

public class ListQueueSet<T>:List<T>
{
    new public void Add(T item) { throw new NotSupportedException(); }
    new public void AddRange(IEnumerable<T> collection) { throw new NotSupportedException(); }
    new public void Insert(int index, T item) { throw new NotSupportedException(); }
    new public void InsertRange(int index, IEnumerable<T> collection) { throw new NotSupportedException(); }
    new public void Reverse() { throw new NotSupportedException(); }
    new public void Reverse(int index, int count) { throw new NotSupportedException(); }
    new public void Sort() { throw new NotSupportedException(); }
    new public void Sort(Comparison<T> comparison) { throw new NotSupportedException(); }
    new public void Sort(IComparer<T> comparer) { throw new NotSupportedException(); }
    new public void Sort(int index, int count, IComparer<T> comparer) { throw new NotSupportedException(); }
    new public void Remove(T item) { throw new NotSupportedException(); }

    private Dictionary<string, T> entries;

    public ListQueueSet()
    {
        entries = new Dictionary<string, T>();
    }

    public void Enqueue(T item, string uniqueID)
    {
        if (entries.ContainsKey(uniqueID))
        {
            int index = base.IndexOf(entries[uniqueID]);
            base.Remove(entries[uniqueID]);
            base.Insert(index, item);
            entries[uniqueID] = item;
        }
        else
        {
            base.Add(item);
            entries.Add(uniqueID, item);
        }
    }

    public T Dequeue()
    {
        var t = base[0];
        base.RemoveAt(0);

        entries.Remove(entries.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Value.Equals(t)).Key);
        return t;
    }

    public T Peek()
    {
        return base[0];
    }
}
```

Comment: You should not be inheriting from `List` at all.  As it is anyone using your collection can just add/edit/update any items and now it's out of sync with your dictionary.  Favor composition over inheritance, and simply have a private list. (or, since you want a queue, a `Queue`).  It's very rarely appropriate to inherit from any collection type.

Comment: @Servy the default methods, such as add/edit/update are disabled by throwing exceptions when they are called. I can upload entire class definition

Comment: But why expose those methods at all if you can avoid it?

Comment: @Magnus , fair point, however this seems like a more interesting approach + it is a bit more efficient way to do it

Comment: Your defence against Add() is paper thin:  `IList<X> param = someListQueueSet;`

Comment: @MartynasAntipenkovas The existing methods such as Add, the indexer, remove, etc. *are not virtual*, and as such you cannot change their behavior at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int index = base.IndexOf(entries[uniqueID]);
this[index] = item;
entries[uniqueID] = item;
```

apparently, `this[index]` allows you to access inside of the list you declare

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments you should not inherit from List and expose all those functions that you dont need. For anyone using your data structure that will just be confusing. Also using an `OrderedDictionary` would make your code more simple as it can be accessed both by key and index.

```
public class MyQueue<T>
{ 
    private OrderedDictionary items = new OrderedDictionary();

    public void Enqueue(T item, string uniqueID)
    {
        if(items.Contains(uniqueID))
            items[uniqueID] = item;
        else
            items.Add(uniqueID, item);
    }

    public T Dequeue()
    {
        var item = items[0];
        items.RemoveAt(0);
        return (T)item;
    }

    public T Peek()
    {
        return (T)items[0];
    }
}
```

Also your effort to prevent usage of the List functions can easily be circumvented by casting to a base type.

```
var queue = new ListQueueSet<int>();
((List<int>)queue).Add(1); //This will add 1 to the collection
```